# How to create a NotifyIcon from a BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, bitmapimage, notifyicon

I have a resource item (a png file) in my resource dictionary which I'm using in several places. Now I want to use it as application's `NotifyIcon`. But I don't know how to do this. Have you any idea please?

```
// my image:

var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProj.Resources;component/Icons/Logo_48x48.png");

// and I try to do this:

var iconHandle = bitmap.GetHicon(); // but this line doesn't work
var ni = new NotifyIcon {
    Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle),
    Visible = true
};
```

Comment: A simple solution is to just store an icon instead of a bitmap.  So you don't have to convert anything.  You can create one with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

```
var sri = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProj.Resources;component/Icons/Logo_48x48.png"));
var bitmap = new Bitmap(sri.Stream);
var handle = bitmap.GetHicon();
var ni = new NotifyIcon {
    Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(handle),
    Visible = true
};
```